# Firefox users getting intermittent Connection Reset errors when downloading Zip files

Tags: iis, web-server, iis-7, connection

I've got a site running on IIS7. Intermittently, Firefox users will get 0k files, as a result of a "Connection Reset", when downloading large zip files. Usually these are in the range of 70-100MB in size.

I see nothing in the IIS logs that helps.

I'm seeking insight on how to debug this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried troubleshooting and look at logs using the following method? http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/266/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7/

Comment: Great. I'll give that a shot.